# jQuery - Hide other divs when clicking new div

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have written this code, that shows a menu (div) when clicking another div. The problem is that when I have one of the menus open, and click the div to open a new menu (there are multiple menus looped out), the other menus do not close. This means I can open an unlimited number of menus simultaneously as long as I am not clicking outside the div/menu...

Short: I want all open menu divs to hide when clicking to open a new menu, except from the menu I just opened...

Code:

```
$('.commentSettings').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#mod-dropdown' + id).stop().toggle(200);
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#mod-dropdown' + id).show();

    $(document).click(function(){
        $("#mod-dropdown" + id).hide();
    });
 });
```

Comment: A little more context, or a sample jsfiddle. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give all divs you want to hide a class, for example `menu`, then you simply could pop `$('.menu').hide();` at the start of the click function.

Note that you have a document ready inside the function and I don't think you wanted to put that there. The document.ready function should always appear first, and you register your event handlers inside that.

Comment: Hmm, where do you find the document ready? I can not find a document.ready inside the function :S

Comment: I apologise I misread the `$(document).click(function...`. But even then I don't think you want to add that handler inside the first click function.

Comment: `$('[id^="#mod-dropdown"]').hide();` isn't faster method?

Comment: That's a CSS3 selector, not adding a variable to the jQuery selector. And id's only target one element instead of all elements if you're trying to hide them all.

Comment: That's jQuery `attributeStartsWith` selector. Look on my answer. There is link to jQuery documentation.

Comment: Sorry yes your method would be faster than a class selector.

Comment: Putting  $(document).click(func.. outside the function makes the script not work. At that point, the menu will not close when clicking outside the menu...

Answer (score 0):

I presume all menus have a common class. Use this to close all menus first. Then open the one currently clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
var id = -1;
$('.commentSettings').click(function(e) {
    if( id != -1 )
        $('#mod-dropdown' + id).hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#mod-dropdown' + id).stop().toggle(200);
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#mod-dropdown' + id).show();

    $(document).click(function(){
        $("#mod-dropdown" + id).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yup. As long as there is no `#mod-dropdown-1` present.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 $('.commentSettings').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#mod-dropdown' + id).stop().toggle(200);
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#mod-dropdown' + id).show();
 });

 $(document).click(function(){
    $('[id^="#mod-dropdown"]').hide();
});
```

I use here jQuery `attributeStartsWith` selector.

More info you can find here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Unfortunately this script does not work entirely. When clicking outside the menu, the menu is not closed...